# load or Inject ContextMenuView to TreeView Directly

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, .net-core, mvvm

I have Created a ContextMenu Separately and want to Inject that View to the Specific View Where TreeView is defined and once user Select any Item in Tree view then this Context Menu should be loaded.

**MultiViewContextMenuView**

```
`    <ContextMenu x:Class="ContextView.UserControls.TopologySelector.MultiViewContextMenu"
      xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
     xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
   xmlns:viewModel="clr-namespace:ContextView.ViewModels.TopologySelector"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Height="450" Width="800"\>

    <ContextMenu.DataContext>
        <viewModel:MultiViewContextMenuViewModel/>
    </ContextMenu.DataContext>
    
    <MenuItem Header="{Binding Header}" HorizontalContentAlignment="Left" Style="{StaticResource            titledContextMenuItem}"/>
    <MenuItem>
        <MenuItem.Header>
            <Label Content="Open in new window..." Style="{StaticResource    ContextMenuLabelStyle}" Margin="8,0,0,0"/>
        </MenuItem.Header>
    </MenuItem>
    <MenuItem>
        <MenuItem.Header>
            <Label Content="View recorder videos..." Style="{StaticResource ContextMenuLabelStyle}" Margin="8,0,0,0"/>
        </MenuItem.Header>
    </MenuItem>
    <MenuItem>
        <MenuItem.Header>
            <Label Content="Create bookmark" Style="{StaticResource ContextMenuLabelStyle}" Margin="8,0,0,0"/>
        </MenuItem.Header>
    </MenuItem>
    <Separator/>
    <MenuItem>
        <MenuItem.Header>
            <Label Content="Show on Stations view..." Style="{StaticResource ContextMenuLabelStyle}" Margin="8,0,0,0"/>
        </MenuItem.Header>
    </MenuItem>
    <MenuItem>
        <MenuItem.Header>
            <Label Content="Go to Bookmarks..." Style="{StaticResource ContextMenuLabelStyle}" Margin="8,0,0,0"/>
        </MenuItem.Header>
    </MenuItem>
    <MenuItem>
        <MenuItem.Header>
            <Label Content="Go to Stream reservations..." Style="{StaticResource ContextMenuLabelStyle}" Margin="8,0,0,0"/>
        </MenuItem.Header>
    </MenuItem>
    <MenuItem>
        <MenuItem.Header>
            <Label Content="Go to Alarms..." Style="{StaticResource ContextMenuLabelStyle}" Margin="8,0,0,0"/>
        </MenuItem.Header>
    </MenuItem>
    <Separator/>
    <MenuItem HorizontalAlignment="Left" Command="{Binding AddToLiveContentCommand}">
        <MenuItem.Header>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Image  Margin="-30,0,10,0" Style="{StaticResource PinboardImageStyle}" Source="{StaticResource SelectedPin}"/>
                <Label Style="{StaticResource ContextMenuLabelStyle}" Content="Pin/unpin"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </MenuItem.Header>
    </MenuItem>

\</ContextMenu\>
```

`

**TreeViewSample**

```
  <TreeView Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding DirItems}" BorderBrush="Transparent"    Background="Transparent"
                  ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"   ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"
                  ContextMenuService.IsEnabled="True" ContextMenu="{DynamicResource }">


             <TreeView.Resources>

                <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type model:DirectoryItem}" ItemsSource=" {Binding Items}">
                    <DockPanel>

                        <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked}" Margin="0"/>

                        <Image Height="{Binding HeightIcon}" Width="{Binding WidthIcon}" Source="{Binding Path=DeviceIconSource}"/>
                        
                        <Ellipse Height="{Binding FunctionalStatusHeight}" Width="{Binding FunctionalStatusWidth}" Margin="3"
                                 Fill="{Binding FunctionalStatus, Converter={StaticResource integerToColorConverter},
                            UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
                        
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}" FontSize="15" Margin="0"/>
                        
                    </DockPanel>
                </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
            </TreeView.Resources>
        </TreeView>
```

> Wanted to load MultiViewContextMenuView in TreeViewSample under  TreeView ContextMenu .Please Help me out if something missing. Thanks

Comment: I think your context menu should be a resource and it should use the viewmodel which is the datacontext of your treeview.

Comment: Don't create a view model class for every control. This doesn't make sense. The MultiViewContextMenuView must not have its own view model class. If you like to bind the MenuItem elements to an ICommand you can bind to the ContextMenu.DataContext or the DataContext of the ContextMenu.PlacementTarget. Also you generally don't set the DataContext of a control internally. The DataContext is inherited from the context the control is used in (parent control).

Comment: You can also always use routed commands with your ContextMenu.

Answer (score 0):

## Solution #1

Simply handle the `SelectedItemChanged` event of the `TreeView`. If you chose to define `MultiViewContextMenuView` as a recource, don't use `DynamicResource` to reference it (like in your example). Use `StaticResource` instead.

```xml
<TreeView SelectedItemChanged="TreeView_SelectedItemChanged">
  <TreeView.ContextMenu>
    <MultiViewContextMenuView />
  </TreeView.ContextMenu>
</TreeView>
```

```cs
private void TreeView_SelectedItemChanged(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<object> e)
{
  var treeView = sender as TreeView;
  if (treeView.ContextMenu is not null
    && treeView.SelectedItem is not null)
  {
    treeView.ContextMenu.IsOpen = true;
  }
}
```

## Solution #2

Create a custom behavior. The following attached behavior supports any routed event to be used to trigger the context menu:

**ContextMenuDisplayService.cs**

```cs
public class ContextMenuDisplayService : DependencyObject
{
  public static ContextMenu GetContextMenu(DependencyObject attachedElement)
    => (ContextMenu)attachedElement.GetValue(ContextMenuProperty);

  public static void SetContextMenu(DependencyObject attachedElement, ContextMenu value)
    => attachedElement.SetValue(ContextMenuProperty, value);

  public static readonly DependencyProperty ContextMenuProperty =
    DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
      "ContextMenu",
      typeof(ContextMenu),
      typeof(ContextMenuDisplayService),
      new PropertyMetadata(default));

  public static RoutedEvent GetTriggerEvent(DependencyObject attachedElement)
    => (RoutedEvent)attachedElement.GetValue(TriggerEventProperty);

  public static void SetTriggerEvent(DependencyObject attachedElement, RoutedEvent value)
    => attachedElement.SetValue(TriggerEventProperty, value);

  public static readonly DependencyProperty TriggerEventProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
    "TriggerEvent",
    typeof(RoutedEvent),
    typeof(ContextMenuDisplayService),
    new PropertyMetadata(default(RoutedEvent), OnTriggerEventChanged));

  private static void OnTriggerEventChanged(DependencyObject attachingElement, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
  {
    var frameworkElement = attachingElement as FrameworkElement;
    if (e.NewValue is RoutedEvent triggerEvent)
    {
      frameworkElement.AddHandler(triggerEvent, new RoutedEventHandler(OnTriggerEventRaised));
    }
  }

  private static void OnTriggerEventRaised(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
  {
    var frameworkeElement = sender as FrameworkElement;
    ContextMenu contextMenu;
    if (GetContextMenu(frameworkeElement) is ContextMenu unmanagedContextMenu)
    {
      unmanagedContextMenu.Placement = PlacementMode.MousePoint;
      contextMenu = unmanagedContextMenu;
    }
    else
    {
      contextMenu = frameworkeElement.ContextMenu;
    }

    if (contextMenu is null)
    {
      return;
    }

    contextMenu.PlacementTarget = frameworkeElement;
    contextMenu.IsOpen = true;
  }
}
```

### Usage example

```xml
<TreeView local:ContextMenuDisplayService.TriggerEvent="TreeView.SelectedItemChanged">

  <!-- Either define context menu inline -->
  <TreeView.ContextMenu>
    <local:MultiViewContextMenuView />
  </TreeView.ContextMenu>

  <!-- ... or define it using the attached property of the behavior -->
  <local:ContextMenuDisplayService.ContextMenu>
    <local:MultiViewContextMenuView />
  </local:ContextMenuDisplayService.ContextMenu>
</TreeView>
```